# How can I add a 3D model to Swift Playgrounds on my iPad?

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

How can I add a 3d model that I can use in AR Kit on my iPad? On the Swift Playgrounds app. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this from an iPad. The solution I had instead was adding the 3d models to the playground file with a Mac, and then opening the same file on the iPad.

You can then import the model to the scene, despite not being able to see it form iPad Playgrounds still.